# How do I change the Material-UI AppBar background colour?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, template-literals

I'm creating an app using Material-UI components, and have changed the colours in the theme as follows (in src/index.js):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    pale: {
        main: '#FCF4D9',
        contrastText: '#383838'
    }
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <App />
 </ThemeProvider>,
 document.getElementById('root'))
```

Then, in one of my components I want to use this to make the app bar have a pale background.  I'm trying to do this as follows (src/Header/index.js):

```
const Header = () => {

  const theme = useTheme()
  
  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" className="appBar" color={`${theme.palette.pale}`}>
      ...
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

This isn't working - the background just comes out as white.  If I rename "pale" to "primary" and then use

```
color="primary"
```

that works fine, but I already have another colour called "primary" so I can't do it that way.

I suspect that I'm doing the template literal wrongly, but I'm not sure - I've tried various other combinations of brackets, $ sign etc, but this is the only one that compiles. Or is it that I can only use "primary" and "secondary" in there, and not a theme property?  If so, how do I use the theme property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps, Material-UI lets you customize Your own theme.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
    pale: {
     main: '#FCF4D9',
     contrastText: '#383838',
    }
  },
});
```

**UPDATED**

Once you customize your theme, you can use the different colors on your components based on their names.
For example, In your `src/Header/index.js` Component, You can do this:

```
const useTheme = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  header: {
    color: theme.pale.main,
  },
}));

const Header = () => {

    const theme = useTheme()

    return (
        <AppBar position="fixed" className="appBar" color={theme.header}>
        ...
        </AppBar>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to define `header: { color: theme.palette.pale.main}` and then on the AppBar line I used `color={theme.header.color}` but your answer got me there!

Comment: Note that the imports has been updated for MUI in version 5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69785004/3448554