# Material-UI Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I know people have posted similar question on StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me, the errors are not the same nor are the fixes, so I am creating a new post.

The firm that is testing me sent me their Github repository and I need to check out that code, it is a Telegram Web app and they are using Material-UI for their design, I cloned the repo installed `node_modules` and then I got the error from Material-UI ,I followed instructions from other StackOverflow posts but nothing worked for me, uninstalled `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons`, installed them again and still got the same error.

I have tried both NPM and Yarn for installation and nothing. Hope you can help, it is important.

```
./src/Theme.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' in '/Users/Faruk/Desktop/int/telegram-react/src'
```

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: The version is  @material-ui/core@4.12.3

Comment: I think the problem was with another developer not importing it correctly, I used a different import and it worked but now there is a strikethrough on the createMuiTheme on Import import { c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶M̶u̶i̶T̶h̶e̶m̶e̶ } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

Comment: That's because the name is changing to `createTheme` in v5, so in the latest version of v4 both names are exported but `createMuiTheme` is [deprecated](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTheme.d.ts#L48).

Answer (score 18):

As @Ryan [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911647/material-ui-cant-resolve-material-ui-core-styles-createmuitheme/69785004#comment121788612_68911647), `createMuiTheme` has been renamed to `createTheme` in the [latest v4](https://v4.mui.com/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) and in v5. See the migration guide [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#mui-material-styles) for reference.

**V5**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

**V4**

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using material UI V5 or higher, this works;

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about createMuiTheme. but you can use this for importing Styles in Mui. This solved mine **on importing styles only**,

```
import styled from '@material-ui/core';
```

Also it works for Material-ui Box, Paper, Link, Grid all of them. Use like this,

```
import { Grid, Link, makeStyles, Paper,Box, styled} from '@material-ui/core';
```

**But I'm not sure with your theme** .